# JS getting union of all object keys from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have below array of objects:

```
var all = [
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4", fn: "vn"}
];
```

Desired Output:

```
[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, ...., fn];
```

Currently Using:

```
all.reduce((sum, item) => ([...new Set([...sum, ...Object.keys(item)])]), []);
```

Working Example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/priyesh35/pen/zYdGXwQ?editors=1111)

Any suggestions using es6 or any new js feature, for better performance.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve  your example has 5 results from an array of 4 objects. Are you trying to get the final key of the object. Is order guaranteed?

Comment: Yet another option: `new Set(all.map(o => Object.keys(o)).flat())`

Comment: @DamianGreen, desired output is "array of keys of heighest key:value pair object from the given array".

Comment: @FelixKling will it be havening better performance, as again we are having 4 operations.

Comment: *"desired output is "array of keys of heighest key:value pair object from the given array"* That's not the same as getting the union of all keys.  What is it now? *"will it be havening better performance, as again we are having 4 operations"* It doesn't create intermediate objects like your solution. But in the end you'll have to actually measure the performance of different solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You can flatten them into a single object, then take the keys.

```js
var all = [
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4", fn: "vn"}
];

const output = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...all));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var all = [
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4", fn: "vn"}
];

console.log(Object.keys(all[all.length-1]))
```

Comment: This makes an assumption that the last element in the array contains all the keys and all the other elements in the array can be ignored.  It's not clear that's a safe assumption.

Comment: No, any object of the array can have heighest number of key:value pairs, not the last one always.

Comment: I know, but for the given input it shows the right results, why care about conercases if not asked?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object to get a Set of unique keys and then use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the Set back into an array.

```js
var all = [
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4"},
{f1: "v1", f2: "v2", f3: "v3", f4: "v4", fn: "vn"}
];

const res = [...new Set(all.flatMap(Object.keys))];
console.log(res);
```